# synchronized method in derived class

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized

If base class A has a "public synchronized void method(){}" which was not overridden by its derived class B,then
what will the lock be (i.e. will it be the derived class object or the base class object) that is used to access the synchronized method in class B?

Comment: This is *not* a static method, is it?

Comment: No.Not even block synchronized like synchronized(A.class) or synchronized(getClass()) or synchronized(Class.forName("A"))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "base class object".

`synchronized` methods lock on the instance they're called on.

Answer (score 0):

```
public synchronized void method() {  
    ...
};
```

is just the same as

```
public void method() {  
    synchronized(this){
        ...
    }
};
```

And for a super-method `this` means an object of class `B`. So the lock will be on an instance of the object `B`.